# How to change for loop to work efficiently python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, optimization, biopython

I have stuck with this script it would be great if you could help me with your inputs. My problem is that I think the script is not that efficient - it takes a lot of time to end running.

I have a fasta file with around 9000 sequence lines (example below) and What my script does is:

1. reads the first line (ignores lines start with `>`) and makes 6mers (6 character blocks)
2. adds these 6mers to a list
3. makes reverse-complement of previous 6mers (list2)
4. saves the line if non of the reverse-complement 6mers are in the line.
5. Then goes to the next line in the file, and check if it contains any of the reverse-complement 6mers (in list2). If it does, it discards it. If it does not, it saves that line, and reads all reverse complement 6-mers of the new one into the list2 - in addition to the reverse-complement 6-mers that were already there.

my file:

```
>seq1
TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTTATTAGCCGGTTCCAGGTATGCAGTATGAGAA
>seq2
TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGCGCCTTAATGTTGTCAGATGTCGAAGGTTAGAA
>seq3
TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTGTTACAGCGAGTGTTATTCCCAAGTTGAGGAA
>seq4
TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTTACCTGGCTGCAATATGGTTTTAGAGGACGAA
```

and this is my code:

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq

def hetero_dimerization():
    script = sys.argv[0]
    file1 = sys.argv[1]
    list = []
    list2 = []
    with open(file1, 'r') as file:
        for record in SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta'):
            for i in range(len(record.seq)):
                kmer = str(record.seq[i:i + 6])
                if len(kmer) == 6:
                    list.append(kmer)
            #print(record.seq)
            #print(list)

            for kmers in list:
                C_kmer = Seq(kmers).complement()
                list2.append(C_kmer[::-1])
            #print(list2)

            cnt=0
            if any(items in record.seq for items in list2):
                cnt +=1

            if cnt == 0:
                print('>'+record.id)
                print(record.seq)
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hetero_dimerization()
```

It would be great if you could help me to make this code very efficient and fast working - THANK YOU.

Comment: This would be a good candidate for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question earlier today?

Comment: Hey @Mike - I made some changes - please do not downvote the question, I need a quick help - I have already  spent a lot of time on this problem and have not solved it yet - this is urgent - please

Comment: You are shadowing the `list` builtin, not a good practice…

Comment: [Every question is urgent to the one asking it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) - and as pointed out by @C.Nivs if you have working code and you're looking for improvements, codereview would be the better place to post. Just make sure to read the codereview question guidelines.

Comment: dear @gboffi - then how I can make it better?

Comment: Oh, and in the future, instead of reposting a question, consider to offer a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Quote: "a bounty may help attract more attention and more answers".

Comment: Thank you Mike :)

Comment: Could you give a rough estimate of the percentage of positives (i.e., when the reversed complement is in the original sequence)? If it's high enough (this mean testing) you could do better times processing each examer on its own and go to next record as soon as you see a match.

Comment: Actually, all the records are generated randomly so I can not make any rough estimation - but I would say 100 records out of 9000 is pretty decent for my experiment. I feel that the liste2 expands a lot and then it makes the code slow down.

Comment: If only 100 records over 9000 match, then my idea won't work.  That said, we don't have your data  and in your use case it is very possible that optimization depends on the statistics of the data, so I conclude that you're on your own, in other words: it's just you that can benchmark your code on your data...

Comment: @MikeScotty Can you put a bounty on a question having a personal score of 5 ?

Comment: @pippo1980 no, you need at least 75 rep to start a bounty. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges - unless you mean something different with "score"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I am not mistaken, you can pull the `.complement()` call outside the inner for for loop. This also gets rid of the first list.

```py
def hetero_dimerization():
    file1 = sys.argv[1]
    list2 = []
    with open(file1, 'r') as file:
        for record in SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta'):

            complement = record.seq.complement()
            for i in range(len(complement)):
                kmer = str(complement[i:i + 6])
                if len(kmer) == 6:
                    list2.append(kmer[::-1])

            cnt = 0
            if any(items in record.seq for items in list2):
                cnt += 1

            if cnt == 0:
                print('>' + record.id)
                print(record.seq)
```

This change reduced the runtime from 20 seconds to about 0.5 on my machine - for a rather small sample of about 500 sequences.